# Laravel 7 on homestead with npm error "cross-env"

Tags: npm, vuejs2, npm-install, homestead, laravel-7

[**Update**]

Vue complier 2.6.12 triggers this error when I try in `npm clean-install`

```
tarball tarball data for vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 (sha512-KIq15bxxxxxx) seems to be 
corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

[image]

I run `npm cache clean --force` then change both versions to `2.6.11` but Vue changes its version automatically to `2.6.12` and can't get it working

---

I have been trying to install VueJs to a current Laravel 7 project. I reach this command

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

I got a warning of mismatch between Vue and the template compiler so I changed the package.json to make them both the same version

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
```

And changed their version in package-lock.json too.

then I deleted node_modules folder then run `npm install` again. I got multiple errors so I kept running the same command multiple times till it finished installing. Now I'm trying to run `npm run dev` but I get this error

```
errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js 
--progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

[image]

How to fix it and make the application work with VueJs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing `cross-env` calls in `package.json` with `npx cross-env`?

For example,

```
// OLD
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",

// NEW 
 "development": "npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```